# Should I play A Valley Without Wind 2 without playing the first game?

Tags: a-valley-without-wind, a-valley-without-wind-2

I just got *A Valley Without Wind* and its sequel from the Indie Royale Arclight Bundle. Having never played either game, and being a little short on time, what would I miss if I choose to play the sequel without playing the first game? What are the major differences between the two games?

Comment: Judging by the trailers, they seem to be almost the same game, but the first is sci-fi and the second fantasy. Storywise they're not connected; 2 seems to have slightly evolved some of the gameplay mechanics. (Someone who has done more than watch trailers should answer, though!)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Both are kinda post apocalyptic. The first one was rather thrown together with random pictures they found and some bad design decisions (Grind) etc. Then they decided to make a second part and do it right this time. Also, all owners of part 1 got 2 for free. Gotta love Arcengames. The story is not connected and does not really matter anyway imho. The first one is more of a platformer and the second one is a metrovania style rpg.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness they explained that in a blog post right. Can you find the link? I could not.

Comment: @IDS http://christophermpark.blogspot.de/search/label/A%20Valley%20Without%20Wind Lot to read :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gathered the two games are not really related, at least in story. So you could perfectly play two before one.

The developers where not totally happy with the way they made A valley without wind 1 so they offered 2 for free for the owners of 1. At least that is what I can recall. So they just went into a different direction gameplay wise for 2. But left 1 alone so the fans of that game were not disappointed.

See this blog post http://christophermpark.blogspot.nl/2012/09/a-valley-without-wind-2-full-sequel.html

Comment: This might be one of the blog posts that you are talking about: http://christophermpark.blogspot.com/2012/09/a-valley-without-wind-2-full-sequel.html